# Trying to replace the Specific word with another word but i didn't get exact result. Is there any resolution using regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, regex-group

I Want to replace the 'REF ' tag to 'REF:'.

Please check the below code:-

```
def test():
    str_data = "REF PUNE UNIVERCITY BMS:KOLHAPUR UNIVERSITY REF NO : MUMBAI UNIVERSITY"
    tag_list = ["REF ", "BMS:", "REF NO :"]
    for each_value in tag_list:
        if each_value[-1] == " ":
            print(each_value)
            str_data = str_data.replace(each_value, each_value[:-1] + ":")
            print(str_data)

test()
```

I tried to solve it but I got the below output.

`Original String = "REF PUNE UNIVERCITY BMS:KOLHAPUR UNIVERSITY REF NO : MUMBAI UNIVERSITY"`

`My Result = REF:PUNE UNIVERCITY BMS:KOLHAPUR UNIVERSITY REF:NO : MUMBAI UNIVERSITY`

`Expected Result = REF:PUNE UNIVERCITY BMS:KOLHAPUR UNIVERSITY REF NO : MUMBAI UNIVERSITY`

Is there any way to resolve it?  Is there any regex expression?

Comment: So, if `REF NO :` exists, the `REF<space>` should not be trouched in that substring, right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Right

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I didn't try regex but I tried the above code.  there is no role of `BMS:`.  I want to replace 'REF ' tag to 'REF:' that's it

Comment: Like `re.sub(r'\bREF\s+(?!\s*NO\s+:)', 'REF:', text)`?

Comment: It is still unclear if your list is dynamic or not, whether the items are known or not beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a regular expression it's easy to say "match `"REF "` but only if it is not followed by `"NO :"`":

```py
import re

str_data = re.sub(r'REF (?!NO :)', 'REF:', str_data)
```

The negative lookahead `(?!NO :)` means if the text at this point matches `NO :`, do not match.

Comment: I tried the above syntax but I got the below result `REF:PUNE UNIVERCITY BMS:KOLHAPUR UNIVERSITY REF:NO : MUMBAI UNIVERSITY`  Please check the above expected result.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice you have a space between `NO` and `:`; updated. If you want to permit omitting the space, that would be `NO ?:`

Answer (score 0):

First change your REF NO: to ***  then replace back with REF NO:
Here is your answer:

```
def test():
    str_data = "REF PUNE UNIVERCITY BMS:KOLHAPUR UNIVERSITY REF NO : MUMBAI UNIVERSITY"
    str_data = str_data.replace("REF NO :", '***').replace("REF ", 'REF: ').replace('***', 'REF NO :')
    return str_data
print(test())
```

Comment: @Akshay This is the shortest possible solution

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def test():
    str_data = "REF PUNE UNIVERCITY BMS:KOLHAPUR UNIVERSITY REF NO : MUMBAI UNIVERSITY"
    str_data = str_data.split("REF NO :")
    for index,data in enumerate(str_data):
        if "REF " in data:
            data = data.replace("REF ", "REF :")
            print(data)
            str_data[index] = data


    print("REF NO :".join(str_data))

test()
```

Answer (score 0):

This will fix in regex format

```
def test():
    import re
    str_data = "REF PUNE UNIVERCITY BMS:KOLHAPUR UNIVERSITY REF NO : MUMBAI UNIVERSITY"
    str_data = re.sub(r'\bREF\s+(?!\s*NO\s+:)', 'REF:', str_data)
    return str_data
print(test())
```